# Jest cannot find file in src tag using Nuxt/Vue

Tags: vue.js, jestjs, nuxt.js, ts-jest

I have a `.vue` file in which I load the a `ts` file this way:

PasswordField.vue

```
<script lang="ts" src="@/assets/ts/components/form/password-field.ts"></script>
```

When I run `yarn test` to test with Jest I get this as output:

```
ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/Users/dir/Projects/dir/dir/07 - browser application/code/components/form/@/assets/ts/components/form/password-field.ts'
```

How can I make sure Jest handles the `@` to go to the parent successfully?

Thanks so much,
Maarten

Answer (score 0):

I think '@' wont work. Instead use the code below:

```
<script lang="ts" src="~assets/ts/components/form/password-field.ts"></script>
```

Comment: Thank you. But both `~assets` and `~/assets` also do not work. Apparently I had to use `../../`